# My google ads were rejected due to the error "Compromised site: content loaded from arclk.net". arclk.net points to 127.0.0.3

Tags: google, advertising

My google ads were rejected due to the error

> Compromised site: content loaded from arclk.net.

Interestingly arclk.net points to `127.0.0.3`. I couldn't find much information about it online. How can I fix my website and hence approve my google ads?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What type of site is it?  If it is based on WordPress, they have a guide for cleaning up your hacked site.